# expo node_modules\react-native-safe-area-context\src\SafeArea.types.ts: Property specifiers expected type of array but got null

Tags: react-native, expo

While upgrading expo SDK from version 30 to 41 I got this error:

```
Android Bundling failed 7033ms
node_modules\react-native-safe-area-context\src\SafeArea.types.ts: C:\react-native\stock-check\node_modules\react-native-safe-area-context\src\SafeArea.types.ts: Property specifiers expected type of array but got null
```

Comment: did you found a solution?